# Best way to compare a local file to a remote file http

Tags: shell, synchronization, http, hashsum

I am looking to compare lots of local files with remote files in a http repository. The idea is that a bash script will check every file in the directory and compare with the remote version. If the remote version is different or only present remotely download and replace it.

I am looking at using md5 and maybe creating an md5 dir mirroring the repo with .md5 files. However the only issue is that to get the md5sum for each file can be slow and resource intensive locally as I am dealing with a few GB worth of files.

So my questions is what is the fastest method to compare the files?

Thank you

Comment: compare only the file size + date.

Comment: This is exactly what the `rsync` program is designed to do; detect differences and update the target if it's changed.

Comment: so can you use ```rsync``` with http urls?

Comment: What's the end goal? Why compare the files?



If you want to compare a hash of the two files you will need to either download the remote file in order to hash it or have a way of running the hash command on the remote host. If you are able to run arbitrary commands on the remote host, I suggest using a protocol other than http (such as rsync, which has already been suggested).

Comment: the remote host will be a repo of files for a game server that are publicly accessible. The local machine can be anyone's server that wants to host a game server. So im not sure having anyone login to the remote server with ssh would be a good idea? Unless I can correctly lock it down I guess. Should an update for the game server be released the remote repo can be updated with the new files. The local game server can compare these and download required files. Kind of like how SteamCMD downloads updates to game servers. My idea was for the to use .md5 files that I generate on remote host.

Comment: This is for my project https://gameservermanagers.com. I am investigating the best way to deal with game server updates that don't use SteamCMD but just an archive. I hoping comparing files will reduce bandwidth usage and give a way to verify game files. Specifically thinking of a method for dealing with GoldenEye: Source updates when they are released.

Comment: You might consider using an existing package management system. Almost all of them support easy creation of an index file on the repo server, containing a list of available files and their checksums. Example: http://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2015/07/20/yum-repository-internals/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the wget command with the -N flag. The -N flag causes wget to download only the files that are newer on the server or missing from the local directory.